# abandonment anxiety in 6 year old -- how to teach him he is ok (and undo the damage from when he was young)

Tags: primary-schooler, parents, anxiety

We struggled with certain things as parents do and our boy (now just "B") who is nearly 6 learned that he would be abandoned, he has not been able to develop past this anxiety when he gets highly aroused (ADHD-esque) mostly at home with us, but I think it does affect him in other environments too he just masks it. He was left at nursery from 8 months old. Originally he had a very nurturing one-on-one carer, but she left and he didn't really get the support he needed as one of the youngest in the nursery at the time. There's ASD in the paternal side of my family. He was a forcep quite stressful alarm ringing emergency delivery and had severe reflux and howled for ages after formula feeding, breast feeding didn't work. So you can imagine how the first few months of his life established early a pattern of intense emotions for all of us.

I have ADHD. B is super intense, super fast, and super intelligent. His Mum (now just "Mum") struggles with this hugely. She refused to accept that one of her reactions was wrong for a long time. She mostly has now. But basically, she used to turn her back on him when she couldn't cope with his emotions (at < 2 years old onwards) and walk off -- often upstairs etc. It was horrible to see but I didn't know how to fix it all at the time. She often fell back on blaming me as overreacting because of my own bad experiences in childhood from my parents. I think we're mostly clear now that this wasn't the case and she had things she needed to fix. (imo, PTSD from childbirth/ post-natal depression both of which she steadfastly refused to get help for). Oh, then we had a miscarriage, a month or so later conceived again and covid started a month after that then 8 months later our second was born. Meanwhile we were in and out of lockdown, homeworking, no childcare, no help.... yep. It's been a journey...

The long-term consequence is that B will panic, re-experiences the original trauma and becomes so hyper aroused he has no regulation there and goes from 0 to 100 in a heartbeat. Often we'll hear it from a different room and--the exhausted hard working and always trying parents we are--can't get there quick enough to remind him he is safe etc. to break this cycle and help him develop regulation and forget the fear he learned. Often he is so hyper-focussed on what he's doing, that he simply hasn't heard us. Even when we've gone over to him and made sure he's heard he struggles with stopping his activity and we have to slowly walk off to get on with e.g. bathtime with our other kid. So you see how even now we're compounding it. I'm realising we need to really tackle this now.

He also has this reaction to push me away when I try and comfort him when he is having one of these "freak outs" -- I go in for touchy feely and he pushes me away which is fine for him to do, and I apologise for and give him space. After all, he learned this because from time to time we listened to other peoples **bad** advice to e.g. ignore the bad behaviour and all that dumb bs which just compounded his sense of abandonment.
I've asked Mum to rephrase her support in those moments from "Do you want a hug" to just giving him a hug. But she still struggles with her own emotions, we can only do what we can do. He used to hit her, only her, and for the longest time she didn't accept that this was because of how she treated him.

FYI, given I know how people who try and help people think -- we've had six months of couples therapy which helped hugely. Mum still gets defensive and her best form of defence is usually attack, but we're past a lot of the worst issues.

Community paediatrician won't assess him as his personality "makeup" isn't affecting his schooling, and all that's remarked on is his tendency for anxiety. He is one of those "deep feeling kids" though, and we've improved hugely and he is much more relaxed, isn't hitting us or anything, and welcomes hugs a lot of the time when he is upset.

Anyway, thing is -- we just simply don't have enough time to read parenting books, or prioritise understanding something like this and I could really do with some suggestions. What do you think we can do, I can do, to help him move past this learnt behaviour, and teach him he is OK, safe and move past the trauma?

Thank you peeps, you're wonderful :)

Comment: You will need to make time to read. You will also need to find a pediatrician who does specialise in the type of challenges your boy has. This is very much something that folks on the internet are not in a position to really help with as there is obviously a lot going on. Professional counselling/therapy is the way to go.

Comment: Then I shall magic up time, and a paediatrician with money I don't have, then I will continue therapy which I can no longer afford.
Appreciate your help /s

Comment: I understand those are the challenges you face, but that doesn't make this the place that can solve such problems. There is no alternative to professional help. Not the internet, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: What completely unhelpful comments, from a moderator no less. I'm not entirely sure why you assumed things about me, and continue to condescend.

Comment: I am fully aware that professionals are the ones best suited. Hence why I clearly pointed out that I made efforts to do this. I had hoped that a kind stranger, without empathy fatigue (!) would potentially have a kind pointer. I very much doubt anyone will want to get involved in this thread now. Thanks a lot for that. I doubt I'll return to this stack exchange site....

Comment: You may be disappointed, but in a case as complex and long-running as yours (and we feel with you), any “quick fix” or experimental half-answer has a high chance of causing even more damage to your child. I agree with previous comments, you and your family need a significant amount of effort for lasting changes. See what you have accomplished already, and nothing happened overnight. It’s a process and with a situation as complex as this, it’s pretty much impossible to sum up all relevant bits in one question, then answer in this format. In short, it’s _because_ we care, not because we don’t.

Comment: "she used to turn her back on him when she couldn't cope with his emotions (at < 2 years old onwards) and walk off".
As a mom who had post partum depression for a good 18 months of my child's life, I think putting a infant in a child-safe place, ensuring they're clean and fed, and walking away for a couple minutes to have a break, is an OK thing to do. In that case, the child isn't abandoned. Agreed if this mom was leaving the child in an unsafe place, or being negligent, then that's a different story.